# Why am I getting "array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal" error message?

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, cs50

I was coding a function that receives a string, updates it, and then returns the same string, but with some changes. When I try copying that string in order to change it as an array, I'm getting the error message "array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal".
Here's where I get the error:

```c
string replace(string word)
{
    char updated[] = word;  // The error points out this line
}

>>> // error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
//    char updated[] = word;
           ^
```

I'm trying to create an array of characters, in order to form a string, from a string literal. However, it doesn't seem to work. For now, I just want to understand better how an array of characters work and why this won't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're trying to use `word` as an array initializer.  Is it an initializer list?  No.  Is it a string literal?  No.  So I guess you can't use it that way.

Comment: Quite simply (and presuming "word" is "palabra"), there is no guarantee that the caller of the function is in the same "compilation unit" (source file). If the function has been called from "outside", the compiler cannot possibly know the characteristics of "word"...

Comment: "I'm trying to create an array of characters, in order to form a string, from a string literal.". But `word` is not a string literal. It is a function parameter. If you want to initialize from a string literal, then use a string literal: `char updated[] = "my string literal";`

Comment: @RaymondChen and how can I make precisely my function parameter a string literal?

Comment: @vcordero Will you please show what you `return` from the function too? More precisely, do you intend to `return updated;`?

Comment: Re “from a string literal”: Here is how you know `word` is not a string literal: A literal is a thing whose value is given in its characters—from the Latin for letter. `37` is a literal because you know the value is thirty-seven from the characters “3” and “7”. `"Hello"` is a literal because you know the value is “Hello” from the characters “H”, “e”, “l”, “l”, and “o”. `word` is not a literal because you do not know what its value is; the letters “w”, “o”, “r” and “d” do not tell you what the string in `word` is.

Comment: There are a number of very good answers below. Pick one. (PS: You wrote, "_a function that receives a string, updates it, and then returns the same string_" If the address received by the function IS the address of a "string literal", you will not be able to modify that string in place. "String literals" are not "mutable"..)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: They should show the call too. `replace("foo")` where the function attempts to copy the updated value into the memory pointed to by its `word` parameter will be a problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, both would be valuable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `strcpy`/`memcpy` from `word` to `updated`, but you also need to allocate memory (`malloc`) for `updated`.

What you `return` shouldn't be a `string`, which is a `typedef` for `char*` that `cs50` automatically releases (via an `atexit` callback) when the program exits, because your manual allocation will not be automatically free'd. You should return a `char*` that you later `free`.

Answer (score 0):

`char updated[] = word;` is invalid in C as C language does not have constructors.

You need to:

```
char updated[strlen(word) + 1];
strcpy(updated, word);
```

Comment: The function will have its copy to play with, yes. The OP write, "_from a string literal._" and the function looks like it returns a `char *`... An automatic buffer won't be sufficient to solve this problem.

Comment: @Fe2O3 we do not know what function will return it can return another string not this one

Comment: True 'nuff... Just thought a good answer would extend to _point out_ that the stack copy will go out of scope, AND take into account the OP's mention of sourcing a "string literal" (Then, again, the OP may not be using the correct terminology... Happens, doesn't it?)